# How to print the corresponding value when match found | excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel sheet with 2 sheet names in it

**Sheet 1** and **Sheet 2**

Sheet 1 -> data

[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3pow.png)

Sheet 2 -> data

[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/il3j9.png)

Need to write some condition in sheet one so that need to check the sheet 1 values in sheet 2 if match found return the correspond value in sheet 1

**Result :**

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrjAn.png)

Comment: use [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929)